# Proof given A,B is invertible, involving transposes

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

(Long time observer, first time asking a question, so excuse me if I get any of the rules wrong)

I am having trouble wrapping my head around this problem and presenting the proof.

If I know A, B is invertible, given: $X^{T}$$(BA)^{T}$$A^{T}$=$V^{T}$ I would like to show X = $A^{-1}$$B^{-1}$$A^{-1}$V

This is what I have so far

Given $X^{T}(BA)^{T}A^{T} = V^{T}$  and since we know $A, B$ is invertible then by property of transposes  $(AB)^{T}= B^{T}A^{T}$;

then $X^{T}A^{T}B^{T}A^{T} =V^{T}$;

$(XABA)^{T} = V^{T}$ by transposing both sides - "involution"

$XABA = V$ Then since $ABA $is invertible, it can be moved to the other side

as required I am left with $X = A^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}V$

Any comments or suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is mostly correct, however you should note that

$$V^T = X^TA^TB^TA^T = (ABAX)^T \neq (XABA)^T$$

and so we have

$$ V = ABAX$$
$$ (A^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1})V = (A^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1})ABAX$$

$$ A^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}V = X$$